# Allauth will not return the desired token payload

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have a django-rest-auth project called merchant. within it I have implemented django-restauth and allauth packages with JWT.

Everything works OK. However, I wish to return additional fields in the JWT token and here's my implementation of it.

In app.views.py

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
    'token': token,
    'user': User_Serializer(user, context={'request':request}).data
    }
```

serializers.py

```
class User_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'is_staff']
```

settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'merchant.coin_app.views.jwt_response_payload_handler',
'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT'
}
```

The payload returned does not contain email/is_staff. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I am not sure it is a solution but you seem to have a typo in your return of  jwt_response_payload_handler. It should be
return {
    'token': token,
    'user': User_Serializer(user, context={'request':request}).data
    }

Comment: Hehehe the code has no typo, must have happened when I posted the question here.

Comment: are you getting user key in your payload?

Comment: @ArvindKumar here's what am getting

payload: {username: "admin", iat: 1596656584, exp: 1596658384, user_id: 3, orig_iat: 1596656584}
token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFobWVkX2FkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTk2NjU2NTg0LCJleHAiOjE1OTY2NTgzODQsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTk2...."}

Comment: I desire to return user property is_staff. 

So far my implementation is, I have created a get endpoint where I get the desired property by sending the token value back to my server(/api/get_session/

Comment: can you upload your get_session/ view?

Comment: Also, Your UserSerializer has only three fields - username, email and is_staff. How are you getting exp, iat, orig_iat etc. For this to understand, We need to look at your get_session view code.

Comment: @ArvindKumar

That's why I mentioned, my efforts to override the jwt_response_payload_handler() method doesn't work. Those are the defult values retired when a user is authenticated

Comment: Yes, but can I have a look at your get_session code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered handler in the `JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` setting option is invoked after the JWT token is generated.

The handler requiring customization is [`JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/1.11.0/rest_framework_jwt/serializers.py#L57) which creates the payload object that is tokenized and not `JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER`.

In your project settings, configure

```
JWT_AUTH = {
  'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'merchant.coin_app.views.jwt_payload_handler',
  'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
  'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT'
}
```

Then in your view, extend the result of `rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler`

```py
import rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler as base_jwt_payload_handler

def jwt_response_payload_handler(user):
    payload = base_jwt_payload_handler(user)
    payload['user'] = User_Serializer(user).data
    return payload
```